# MySQL: Subquery: No Output

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I'm working on a subquery. I have a question. What is causing nothing to return? I thought I had made it pretty fluid, but it looks like I'm doing something wrong...is it the WHERE operator?

**Intent:**

I'm attempting to display all items that haven't been ordered. Each item has an item_ID that is included in the order_details. I do have to use a subquery for this.

I didn't get any errors, it just displays nothing. Suggestions?

**Query:**

```
SELECT
        (SELECT items.item_id 
        FROM items 
        ) as 'Item ID'
FROM items
JOIN order_details on order_details.item_ID = items.item_id
WHERE order_details.order_qty < 1
ORDER BY items.item_id ASC;
```

**All other code:**

```
CREATE TABLE items
(
 item_id    INT       NOT NULL,
 title     VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
 artist_id   INT   NOT NULL,
 unit_price  DECIMAL(9,2)  NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT items_pk 
  PRIMARY KEY (item_id),
 CONSTRAINT items_fk_artists
  FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artists (artist_id)
);

CREATE TABLE orders
(
 order_id     INT     NOT NULL,
 customer_id    INT     NOT NULL,
 order_date    DATE    NOT NULL,
 shipped_date   DATE,
 employee_id    INT,
 CONSTRAINT orders_pk
  PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
 CONSTRAINT orders_fk_customers
  FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (customer_id),
CONSTRAINT orders_fk_employees
  FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employees (employee_id)
);

CREATE TABLE order_details
(
 order_id   INT      NOT NULL,
 item_id    INT      NOT NULL,
 order_qty   INT      NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT order_details_pk 
  PRIMARY KEY (order_id, item_id),
 CONSTRAINT order_details_fk_orders
  FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
  REFERENCES orders (order_id),
 CONSTRAINT order_details_fk_items
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
  REFERENCES items (item_id)
);


INSERT INTO items (item_id,title,artist_id,unit_price) VALUES 
(1,'Umami In Concert',10,17.95),
(2,'Race Car Sounds',11,13),
(3,'No Rest For The Weary',12,16.95),
(4,'More Songs About Structures and Comestibles',12,17.95),
(5,'On The Road With Burt Ruggles',13,17.5),
(6,'No Fixed Address',14,16.95),
(7,'Rude Noises',15,13),
(8,'Burt Ruggles: An Intimate Portrait',13,17.95),
(9,'Zone Out With Umami',10,16.95),
(10,'Etcetera',16,17);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES
(19,1,'2012-10-23','2012-10-28',6),
(29,8,'2012-11-05','2012-11-11',6),
(32,11,'2012-11-10','2012-11-13',NULL),
(45,2,'2012-11-25','2012-11-30',NULL),
(70,10,'2012-12-28','2013-01-07',5),
(89,22,'2013-01-20','2013-01-22',7),
(97,20,'2013-01-29','2013-02-02',5),
(118,3,'2013-02-24','2013-02-28',7),
(144,17,'2013-03-21','2013-03-29',NULL),
(158,9,'2013-04-04','2013-04-20',NULL),
(165,14,'2013-04-11','2013-04-13',NULL),
(180,24,'2013-04-25','2013-05-30',NULL),
(231,15,'2013-06-14','2013-06-22',NULL),
(242,23,'2013-06-24','2013-07-06',3),
(264,9,'2013-07-15','2013-07-18',6),
(298,18,'2013-08-18','2013-09-22',3),
(321,2,'2013-09-09','2013-10-05',6),
(381,7,'2013-11-08','2013-11-16',7),
(413,17,'2013-12-05','2014-01-11',7),
(442,5,'2013-12-28','2014-01-03',5),
(479,1,'2014-01-30','2014-03-03',3),
(491,16,'2014-02-08','2014-02-14',5),
(523,3,'2014-03-07','2014-03-15',3),
(548,2,'2014-03-22','2014-04-18',NULL),
(550,17,'2014-03-23','2014-04-03',NULL),
(601,16,'2014-04-21','2014-04-27',NULL),
(607,20,'2014-04-25','2014-05-04',NULL),
(624,2,'2014-05-04','2014-05-09',NULL),
(627,17,'2014-05-05','2014-05-10',NULL),
(630,20,'2014-05-08','2014-05-18',7),
(651,12,'2014-05-19','2014-06-02',7),
(658,12,'2014-05-23','2014-06-02',7),
(687,17,'2014-06-05','2014-06-08',NULL),
(693,9,'2014-06-07','2014-06-19',NULL),
(703,19,'2014-06-12','2014-06-19',7),
(778,13,'2014-07-12','2014-07-21',7),
(796,17,'2014-07-19','2014-07-26',5),
(800,19,'2014-07-21','2014-07-28',NULL),
(802,2,'2014-07-21','2014-07-31',NULL),
(824,1,'2014-08-01',NULL,NULL),
(827,18,'2014-08-02',NULL,NULL),
(829,9,'2014-08-02',NULL,NULL);

INSERT INTO order_details VALUES 
(381,1,1),
(601,9,1),
(442,1,1),
(523,9,1),
(630,5,1),
(778,1,1),
(693,10,1),
(118,1,1),
(264,7,1),
(607,10,1),
(624,7,1),
(658,1,1),
(800,5,1),
(158,3,1),
(321,10,1),
(687,6,1),
(827,6,1),
(144,3,1),
(479,1,2),
(630,6,2),
(796,5,1),
(97,4,1),
(601,5,1),
(800,1,1),
(29,10,1),
(70,1,1),
(165,4,1),
(180,4,1),
(231,10,1),
(413,10,1),
(491,6,1),
(607,3,1),
(651,3,1),
(703,4,1),
(802,3,1),
(824,7,2),
(829,1,1),
(550,4,1),
(796,7,1),
(693,6,1),
(29,3,1),
(32,7,1),
(242,1,1),
(298,1,1),
(479,4,1),
(548,9,1),
(627,9,1),
(778,3,1),
(19,5,1),
(89,4,1),
(242,6,1),
(264,4,1),
(550,1,1),
(693,7,3),
(824,3,1),
(829,5,1),
(829,9,1);
```

Comment: What is the desired intent of the sub query?

Comment: It's not so much that it's desired as it has to be there. I'm supposed to use a subquery to display the items that have not been ordered.

Comment: Why do you need a use a subquery? That is not needed in this case at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE order_details.order_qty < 1 :
```

This fails as in your data no where order_details.order_qty < 1. Since it doesn't have any record with quantity < 1 ,so it displays none.

Since this subquery will return more than 1 row so, in this case it will not work. To display all items that haven't been ordered using a subquery:

```
Select distinct item_id from items where item_id not in (select distinct item_id from order_details);
```

Here, I am taking those item_id which are in items table but not in order details. So this is a list of those items that haven't been ordered.

Comment: I had a bad feeling that was the case.

Comment: Not a problem. But your subquery will return more than one row and hence I doubt if this query will work.

Comment: Even with LIMIT 1 added in?

Comment: Assuming of course that I can figure out the where condition.

Comment: If you use LIMIT 1 , it will give you the first item_id always and hence it will defeat your purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! I see what you mean. And thank you for the guidance as far as correcting my misinterpretations!

Comment: Awesome! No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

you are selecting for order_qty less than 1

```
WHERE order_details.order_qty < 1
```

Here is the updated query for qty > 1:

```
SELECT items.item_id 
FROM items
inner JOIN order_details on order_details.item_ID = items.item_id
WHERE order_details.order_qty > 1
ORDER BY items.item_id ASC;
```

[EDIT]

use this query for items that are yet to be ordered

```
select i.* from items i
left outer join order_details od on od.item_id = i.item_id
where order_qty is null
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I appreciate your assistance, but I'm looking to display the items that haven't yet been ordered. If that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! That is unexpectedly very simple. :)